# How to fix error: Could not find class apache::base?

Tags: puppet

I'm using the following sample manifest from [camptocamp/puppet-nagios](https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-nagios):

```
node 'central_monitoring_server' {
  import "nagios"

  $nagiosadmin_password = "XXXX"

  ...

  include apache::base

  include nagios::base
  include nagios::nsca::daemon
  include nagios::webinterface
}
```

However I've the warning:

> Error: Could not find class `apache::base` for debian-77-wheezy-64

I'm not clear what I should do.

Can I just use:

```
include apache
```

which should be equivalent to `include apache::base`? Is that the correct approach?

I'm using puppet (v3.7.4), camptocamp-nagios (v1.0.4) and puppetlabs-apache (v1.2.0).

Comment: Related: [GitHub #30 Error: Could not find class ::apache_c2c::params](https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-nagios/issues/30)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not referring to puppetlabs-apache.
They expect you to use this one:  https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-apache_c2c

Secondly they've renamed it to `apache_c2c` so it shouldn't conflict anymore. You'll also must use `apache_c2c::base` instead now.

I'm not sure if you can replace it with the puppetlabs-apache module.

Comment: Thank you. Can I have both modules installed in place (puppetlabs-apache for different standalone manifest), and puppet-apache_c2c for this one (nagios manifest)?

Comment: I think yes. They renamed it to `apache_c2c` so it shouldn't conflict anymore. You'll also must use `apache_c2c::base` instead now.